# Not able to generate chart using official Highcharts .Net wrapper in web forms

Tags: .net, highcharts

Below is the code I am using to generate chart using Highcharts .Net wrapper.

```
Highcharts chart = new Highcharts();

chart.Chart = new Chart{ RenderTo = "dv1", Width = 1087,  Height = 400,  Type = ChartType.Column, ClassName=""};

List<Series> series = new List<Series>
{
    new ColumnSeries
    {
        Name = "Brands",
        ColorByPoint = true,
        Data = new List<ColumnSeriesData>
        {
            new ColumnSeriesData { Name = "Microsoft Internet Explorer", Y = 56.3, Drilldown = "Microsoft Internet Explorer" },
            new ColumnSeriesData { Name = "Chrome", Y = 24.03, Drilldown = "Chrome" },
            new ColumnSeriesData { Name = "Firefox", Y = 10.3, Drilldown = "Firefox" },
            new ColumnSeriesData { Name = "Sfari", Y = 4.77, Drilldown = "Safari" },
            new ColumnSeriesData { Name = "Opera", Y = 0.91, Drilldown = "Opera" },
            new ColumnSeriesData { Name = "Proprietary or Undetectable", Y = 0.2, Drilldown = null }                      
        }  
    }    
};
chart.Series = series;


<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="HighCharts.Net_Wrapper._Default" %>


<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server"> 
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/highcharts.js"></script> 

<div id="dv1"></div>
</asp:Content>
```

When I run the page it executes successfully, but chart is not getting generated. Not sure if this will work with ASP.Net web forms as the downloaded package from Highcharts site contains DLL named as Highcharts.Web.Mvc.dll.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: See the answer from Highcharts forum [here](http://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/how-to-use-high-charts-net-wrapper-with-asp-net-web-forms-t37244/) - based on the answer, currently it is not possible.